# Swift - iOS - Convert String to Date & issue

Tags: swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter, foundation

I have an extension on String to convert my date strings to a Date type in Swift 5.2

```
extension String {
  func toDate(withFormat format: String = "MMM d, YYYY HH:mm:ss a") -> Date {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US")
    dateFormatter.calendar = Calendar(identifier:  .iso8601)
    dateFormatter.timeZone = .current
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = format
    guard let date = dateFormatter.date(from: self) else {
      preconditionFailure("Check the format!!!")
    }
    return date
  }
}
```

when I try this to convert my date_string is always wrong(check below) :

```
var sampleDate = "May 5, 2021 1:34:15 AM"
let newDate = sampleDate.toDate()
print(newDate) //prints: "2020-12-28 05:34:15 +0000\n"
```

My date_string that I want to convert is always in a similar format: "May 5, 2020 9:20 5:39:15 PM"

Any idea what could be wrong? I played around with local, calendar, timezone but did not work! I'm in the US East Coast timezone right now.

Thanks,
Cam

Comment: `Y` is for `yearForWeekOfYear`
. you should use `yyyy` instead

Comment: The OP also needs to use "hh" for the 12 hour time if there using "a" to add an AM/PM symbol.

Comment: @DuncanC yes I didn't even look at the time. 2020 was the first thing I saw

Comment: Beware that this will create a new date formatter every time you call this method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your DateFormatter's dateFormat should be `"MMM d, yyyy hh:mm:ss a"`

("yyyy" instead of "YYYY" and "hh" instead of "HH")

That works.

### Edit:

Or, as Leo pointed out in the comments, `"MMM d, yyyy h:mm:ss a"` (With only one `h`) would be better, and it's safer to use

```
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
```

(That tells the date formatter not to try to adjust the date format for different local date formatting conventions.)

Comment: Note that OP should use a single `h` not `hh`. You should also note that OP should use "en_US_POSIX" instead of "en_US" otherwise the date parsing might fail

Comment: It depends on the desired result.  "hh" adds leading zeros. I guess you're right, given that the sample date string does not have leading zeros. That said, it looks like using "hh" still works.

Comment: yes DateFormatter is kind of lenient when parsing. Note that without setting the locale to "en_US_POSIX" the DateFormatter will be affected by the device's locale and settings. Particularly the 12-24h settings which might cause the parsing to fail

Comment: @LeoDabus do you know why the time is being converted wrong? e.g "May 9, 2020 9:15:15 AM" is converted to 2020-05-09 13:15:15

Comment: @Cam Are you printing the date (UTC)? +0000 means zero seconds from GMT. Are your timezone offset +4h?

Comment: @Cam If you want to check the resulting date at the current local use `date.description(with: .current)`

Comment: Yes, the timezone offset is 4h. when I use .description, shows the correct one. Thanks @LeoDabus